# Multiple class files in a Zephir extension

Tags: zephir

I'm doing some experiments with Phalcon Zephir to see how well it can convert some of my libraries to PHP extensions.

I have two PHP classes, each already defined in its own file: the Zephir notes are quite clear that this must be the case.

`trienode.zep`

```
namespace tries;

class trienode
{
    public children;

    public valueNode = false;

    public value = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        let this->children = [];
    }
}
```

and

`trie.zep`

```
namespace tries;

class trie {

    private trie;

    public function __construct() {
        let this->trie = new trienode();
    }
}
```

But whenever I try to compile the classes using `zephir compile`, I get

```
Warning: Class "trienode" does not exist at compile time  in /home/vagrant/ext/tries/tries/trie.zep on 8 [nonexistent-class]

            let this->trie = new trienode();
    ---------------------------------------^
```

(and if I continue through the build process, and install the resultant .so file, it errors when I try to use it from within a PHP script)

```
<?php

namespace tries;

$test = new trie;
```

giving

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/tries.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/tries.so: undefined symbol: zephir_tries_trie_init in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'tries\trie' not found in /home/vagrant/triesTest.php on line 5
```

I've looked through the Zephir documentation, and various blog posts, but can't find any examples of building an extension that comprises more than a single class file.

Has anybody succeeded in building an extension using Zephir that does comprise more than a single class? And if so, what settings or configuration options (or additional steps) does it require to build a working so?

Comment: The question is, how debuggable and maintainable will be the result of that - even if it once compile well?

Comment: @hek2mgl - That's why I'm experimenting to find out

Comment: :) you already got me, now I'm experimenting myself with this.. Need to organize some stuff, will have a look later here.

Comment: @Hek2mgl - it has its quirks as a language, so it's taken me a while to identify why my code wasn't working as it should.... but my Zephir Trie classes now load a 160k dictionary in 43 seconds compared with 96 seconds for the pure PHP version, and do a search in 0.7 seconds compared with 1.1 seconds for the pure PHP.... memory about 0.1% higher (but that's something I can probably address to get at least parity)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I must admit that I didn't more than cloning Zephir and reading the README today. Normally I'm not such a friend of too much tweaking techniques because I think it is often misused. Developers should get a feeling of how performant untweaked code can be - if well written. However, I'm sure that you are aware of that, so using some optimization - like Zephir - could really be interesting here. I'll check it these days (thx for pointing me towards Zephir, +1 ) .. Have you compared the results to hhvm? (maybe stupid question but hhvm is still on my list)

Comment: It took a fair bit of reading the language documentation to convert my existing files. Some changes are simple, stripping `$` from variable names, making sure they're all declared before using them, prefixing assignments with `let`, etc. Control structures such as `foreach` are slightly more interesting - foreach($array as $key => $value) {}` becomes `for key, value in array {}`, which feels nice and clean.

Comment: But a `while (value1 < value2) {}` loop simply didn't execute without moving the comparison outside of the statement and just comparing a single variable; and you can't reference characters in a string using `a[i]` or `a{i}` syntax; likewise it isn't happy with `i++`, though it accepts `let i++` which feels ugly, or `let i +=1`

Comment: I'm still going to devote a bit of time and effort to exploring just what it's capable of though

Comment: Thx for all that info, appreciating this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the namespace has to be included in the call.

```
let this->trie = new tries\trienode();
//                   ^^^^^^
```

I didn't see this explicitly mentioned in the documentation, but is hinted at (pardon the pun) in the [Return Type Hints](http://zephir-lang.com/oop.html#return-type-hints) section, which uses the namespace in the hints.

Changing your example class to that shown above allows the extension to compile as desired.

Comment: Thanks Peter... definitely one of the quirks of Zephir, the namespace declaration seems to be purely for the benefit of the compiler bundling the classes into a package, and all namespaced classes referenced in the code seem to need absolute namespacing